# IF statement doesn't work in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got this function but I don't know if "switch" would be better?

```
(function ($) {
    var doc = $.urlParam('doc');
    if (doc) {
        if (doc = 'new') {
            alert(doc);
        }
        if (doc = 'new2') {
            alert(doc);
        }
        if (doc = 'new3') {
            alert(doc);
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

The alert should only show up if the parameter in the URL is right, like in the IF statement.

The complete code can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/yc5f9ct7/4/

Comment: Firstly, use `==` to check equality. Secondly, given that all three conditions execute the same logic, whats the point of the `if` statement in the first place?

Comment: Use `==` or `===` instead `=`, remember `=` is assignment operator

Comment: Also note: it *looks* like your code wants to wrap that last part in a DOM ready handler, but you are wrapping it in a IIFE instead. Change the wrapper to just this: `jQuery(function($){ YOUR CODE });` This shortcut provides DOM ready and a locally scoped `$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As everyone pointed out, you are using assignment `=` instead of comparison `==` or exact comparison `===`.

That aside, if you are testing one variable for multiple values, and intend to have different code on each, then a switch is more logical:

```
var doc = $.urlParam('doc');
switch (doc){
    case 'new':
        alert(doc);
        break;
    case 'new2':
        alert(doc);
        break;
    case 'new3':
        alert(doc);
        break;
}
```

Also note: it *looks* like your code wants to wrap that last part in a DOM ready handler too, but you are wrapping it in a IIFE instead. Change the wrapper to `jQuery(function($){ YOUR CODE HERE });`

e.g.

```
jQuery(function($){
    var doc = $.urlParam('doc');
    switch (doc){
        case 'new':
            alert(doc);
            break;
        case 'new2':
            alert(doc);
            break;
        case 'new3':
            alert(doc);
            break;
    }
});
```

This handy shortcut for *DOM ready*, provides a locally scoped `$`.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `==` instead of `=` to check equality in if statements:

```
 (function ($) {

 var doc = $.urlParam('doc');


 if (doc) {
        if (doc == 'new') {
            alert(doc);

        }
        if (doc == 'new2') {
            alert(doc);

        }
        if (doc == 'new3') {
            alert(doc);

        }
    }

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks, it was kind of late, yesterday :)

Comment: It looks from the JSFiddle like they meant to have a *DOM ready handler* too, but are using an IIFE instead.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, double equals required, but you could also shorten this to:

```
(function ($) {
    var doc = $.urlParam('doc');
    if (doc) {
        if (doc == 'new' || doc == 'new2' || doc == 'new3') {
            alert(doc);
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Could be shortened still to `if (doc && (doc == 'new' || doc == 'new2' || doc == 'new3')) {` ...